# How to make login system with access levels with users registered in different tables?

Tags: php, html, sql

I would like to be told how do I create a php login system with access levels, but with users registered in different SQL tables. 
Some time ago, I made a login system also with access levels, but with users registered in a single table, ie, what set them apart was a field that I created in the table called "id_permissoes".

This was the code you used:

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

  // Verifica se não há a variável da sessão que identifica o usuário

  if ($_SESSION['nivelAcesso'] == 1) {
      // Redireciona o visitante de volta pro login
      header("Location: admin"); 
  }

  if ($_SESSION['nivelAcesso'] == 2) {
      // Redireciona o visitante de volta pro login
      header("Location: co"); 
  }

  if ($_SESSION['nivelAcesso'] == 3) {
      // Redireciona o visitante de volta pro login
      header("Location: cc"); 
  }

// Include config file
require_once "config.php";

// Inicializa variáveis
$email = $password = "";
$email_err = $password_err = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if(isset($_REQUEST["submit"])){

    // Verifica e-mail vazio
    if(empty(trim($_REQUEST["email"]))){
        $email_err = "Introduza o seu email.";
    } else{
        $email = trim($_REQUEST["email"]); // trim -retira espaços no princípio ou fim da string
    }

    // Verifica password vazia
    if(empty(trim($_REQUEST["password"]))){
        $password_err = "Introduza a sua password.";
    } else{
        $password = trim($_REQUEST["password"]); // trim -retira espaços no princípio ou fim da string
    }

    // Valida credenciais
    if(empty($email_err) && empty($password_err)){
        // Prepara select statement
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id_admin, nome, apelido, email, password, id_permissoes, primeiro_acesso FROM administradores WHERE email = :email");

        if($stmt){
            // Faz o bind das variáveis com os parametros do statement
            $stmt->bindParam(":email", $param_email);

            // Set parameters
            $param_email = trim($_REQUEST["email"]);

            // Executa o statement
            if($stmt->execute()){
                // Verifica se o email existe na base de dados. Se sim, valida a password
                if($stmt->rowCount() == 1){
                    if($row = $stmt->fetch()){
                        $id = $row["id_admin"];
                        $email = $row["email"];
                        $nome = $row["nome"];
                        $apelido = $row["apelido"];
                        $permissoes = $row["id_permissoes"];
                        $primeiro_acesso = $row["primeiro_acesso"];

//                        $hashed_password = $row["password"];
                        if($password===$row["password"]){
//                        if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){

                            // Password correta, inicia sessão
                           if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

                            // Guardar autenticação em variáveis de sessão
                            $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                            $_SESSION["email"] = $email;
                            $_SESSION["nome"] = $nome;
                            $_SESSION["nivelAcesso"] = $permissoes;
                            $_SESSION["apelido"] = $apelido;
                            $_SESSION["primeiro_acesso"] = $primeiro_acesso;

                            // Redireccionar para a página de acolhimento

                            if(isset($_SESSION['destino']) && $_SESSION['destino'] != "") {
                                header("Location: ".$_SESSION['destino']);

                            }else{
                                if($_SESSION["nivelAcesso"] == "1"){
                                header("Location: admin");

                            }elseif($_SESSION["nivelAcesso"] == "2"){
                                header("Location: co");

                            }else{
                                header("Location: cc");

                            }
                            }


                        } else{
                            // Mensagem de erro, caso password errada
                            $password_err = "A password que introduziu não é válida.";
                        }
                    }
                } else{
                    // Mensagem de erro, caso user não exista
                    $email_err = "Email não existente.";
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Alguma coisa correu mal aqui.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        unset($stmt);
    }

    // Close connection
    unset($pdo);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>CC | BackOffice</title>
  <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css">
  <!-- Ionicons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
  <!-- icheck bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/icheck-bootstrap/icheck-bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Theme style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/adminlte.min.css">
  <!-- Google Font: Source Sans Pro -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="hold-transition login-page">
<div class="login-box">
  <div class="login-logo">
    <a href="#"><b>CC</b>BackOffice</a>
  </div>
  <!-- /.login-logo -->
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body login-card-body">
      <p class="login-box-msg">Digite os seus dados para iniciar sessão</p>

      <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
                                <div class="form-group" <?php echo (!empty($email_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                                    <label>email</label>
                                    <input class="au-input au-input--full" type="text" name="email" placeholder="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" autofocus>
                                    <span style="color:red;" class="help-block"><?php echo $email_err; ?></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group" <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                                    <label>Password</label>
                                    <input class="au-input au-input--full" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                                    <span style="color:red;" class="help-block"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="login-checkbox">
                                    <label align="right">
                                        <a href="https://m.me/filipengine">Problemas no acesso?</a>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <button class="au-btn au-btn--block au-btn--green m-b-20" type="submit" name="submit">Entrar</button>
                            </form>
    </div>
    <!-- /.login-card-body -->
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.login-box -->

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
<script src="plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="dist/js/adminlte.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

However, now the need has arisen to create 3 different tables to separate user types.

How do I do this validation?

I tried to test some if's (if it doesn't exist in one table, fetch in the other), but couldn't.

Can you help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you write the comments in english?

Comment: Just don't store the same entity type, users, in three different tables. That would be a horrible design. Stay with one table only.

Comment: " users registered in different SQL tables."...why? Just change the table design.

Comment: I posted the version of code I made for one table to see if it was possible to adapt to 3 tables. I asked if anyone explains to me how to do this with 3 tables, because I need it in a university project. There will be 3 types of users (3 tables) with different fields, so you need to separate users...

Comment: Could have been nice to show the tables structures

Comment: @FilipeMartins its possible! but you need to ask them to login on their types, example you can create a required select box in login.php like `<option>Bussiness</option><option>individual</option>` if selected bussiness then redirect login for bussiness, if selected individuals then redirect to individuals login, there are several ways to do that, you have to be clear in your question and ask what you want.

Comment: _"There will be 3 types of users (3 tables) with different fields, so you need to separate users"_ ...no, you don't. Just have some optional fields in the table to store those attributes, and only complete the ones which are relevant to that user's type. Or you could have one central "users" table, and then some child tables which store data specific for each type of user (with a 1 to 1 relation between them). Having 3 completely separate lists of users will give you a denormalised schema, and that will just continually cause you problems, starting with the one you're asking about here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure 100% what you asking, What I understand is you are asking for redirection users to their role page.

I use to try that in a project with switch statements

- Create a column call Role in your user table then add roles like :
- role = 1 is admin
- role = 2 is employees
- role = 3 is normal user
- role = 0 is unverified

Than redirect user where you get success and set sessions variables like this.

```
$_SESSION['role'] = $role; 
$role = intval($row['role']);
switch ($role){
case 0:
header("location: ../user/?log=activation");
break;
case 1: 
header("location: ../admin/index.php");
break;
case 2:
header("location: ../Upanel/");
break;
case 3:
header("location: ../Upanel/");
break;
}
```

Hope this will give you an idea.

I realy dont understand what means login in 2 table :)

**EDIT:** Redirection users to login on their types :

> Login with 3 tables add a simple condition like following into your login.php

```js
    $(function(){
      // bind change event to select
      $('#dynamic_select').on('change', function () {
          var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value
          if (url) { // require a URL
              window.location = url; // redirect
          }
          return false;
      });
    });
```

```html
<select id="dynamic_select">
  <option value="" selected>Please select login type</option>
  <option value="teacherLogin.php">Teacher</option>
  <option value="studentLogin.php">Student</option>
  <option value="adminLogin.php">Admin</option>
</select>
```